# Form submitting with jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to submit a form with jquery and ajax, but code does not work.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( '#myForm' ).submit( function( evt ) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      var $form = $( this );
      $.ajax( {
        type: $form.prop( 'method' ),
        url: $form.prop( 'action' ),
        data: $form.serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        success: function( response ) {
          alert("it works!");
          document.body.innerHTML = response;
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Solved my problem by changing code a bit:

I solved my problem by changing url,type.

And I settled to change  div with id=mylist. Now it works.

```
<script>
                      $( function() {
                          $( '#paieska' ).submit( function( evt ) {
                              evt.preventDefault();   
                              $.ajax({
                                  url: "/Transport/Lentele",
                                  type: 'POST',
                                  data: $("#paieska").serialize(),
                                  success: function (response) {
                                      $("#mylist").html(response);                            
                                  }                           
                              });                                
                          });
                      });
                  </script>
```

I'll add this as solution when I will be available to.

Comment: did you see something in console? any bug report?

Comment: Is there any error you can see in the console?

Comment: did you see any ERROR in console?

Comment: add this: contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" to $.ajax({

Comment: No errors in console.

Comment: It's impossible to tell what the problem is given just the code. You also have to supply the error message you got, and probably the html form so we can see what values you are submitting.

Comment: Go to developer tools. Look at network requests.

Comment: See if your expected url got called, and if so, what the response was.

Comment: You may refer on this link http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Added contentType, but It still does not work.

Comment: @JustinaSeliokaite: I think this code must be execute. Example http://jsfiddle.net/clickthelink/Uwcuz/1/

Comment: I get this error after adding contenttype: POST http://localhost:3043/transport/grid/Index 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: just make sure your action path should be correct...and what type of data you are returning from other page???

Comment: To be clear: I'm making a search form. I enter some data and then return data I find in db and load.

I'm returning model from controller

Comment: Action path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

what is the response code for this url(the one in AJAX). you check it inside Net, in developer tools..
also, by seeing this only, i can tell that you should not be using preventdefault, might be it starts working...

Comment: If I remove preventdefault form reloads (but without ajax)